# Typescript (or angular2) Error: No provider for RuntimeMetadataResolver

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm **new** in Typescript/Angular2 languages. I'm trying to develop sample application from a Typescript book but I always get the following error:

```
No provider for RuntimeMetadataResolver (ComponentResolver -> RuntimeCompiler -> RuntimeMetadataResolver)
```

in the browser console.
I think the problem is in component version in packages.json.
Angular2 has been installed using npm install so the version is 2.0beta17.

Stacktrace:

```
BaseException@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:25797:23 [angular]
AbstractProviderError@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:26406:9 [angular]
NoProviderError@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:26442:9 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._throwOrNull@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27967:19 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKeyDefault@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27995:20 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKey@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27958:20 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByReflectiveDependency@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27948:16 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._instantiate@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27845:31 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._instantiateProvider@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27817:20 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._new@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27806:16 [angular]
ReflectiveInjectorDynamicStrategy.prototype.getObjByKeyId@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27461:36 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKeyDefault@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27986:23 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKey@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27958:20 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByReflectiveDependency@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27948:16 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._instantiate@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27845:31 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._instantiateProvider@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27817:20 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._new@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27806:16 [angular]
ReflectiveInjectorDynamicStrategy.prototype.getObjByKeyId@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27461:36 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKeyDefault@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27986:23 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype._getByKey@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27958:20 [angular]
ReflectiveInjector_.prototype.get@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:27767:16 [angular]
coreLoadAndBootstrap/<@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:36582:33 [angular]
ApplicationRef_.prototype.run/<@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:36774:26 [angular]
NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvoke@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:32701:32 [angular]
Zone.prototype.run@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:117:24 [<root> => angular]
NgZoneImpl.prototype.runInner@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:32732:60 [<root>]
NgZone.prototype.run@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:32968:51 [<root>]
ApplicationRef_.prototype.run@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:36772:9 [<root>]
coreLoadAndBootstrap@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:36581:12 [<root>]
bootstrap@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:68267:12 [<root>]
@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:68328:1 [<root>]
@file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:1:2 [<root>]
  index.js:45341:13
    BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.logError file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:45341:13
    ExceptionHandler.prototype.call file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:25704:13
    ApplicationRef_.prototype.run/< file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:36783:17
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:233:17
    NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvoke file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:32701:32
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:232:17
    Zone.prototype.run file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:117:24
    NgZoneImpl.prototype.runInner file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:32732:60
    NgZone.prototype.run file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:32968:51
    ApplicationRef_.prototype.run file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:36772:9
    coreLoadAndBootstrap file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:36581:12
    bootstrap file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:68267:12
    <anonimo> file:///C:/ProgettiWeb/TestAngular/Chapter2/static/scripts/index.js:68328:1
    <anonimo>
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "weather-widget",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "small": "^0.2.7"
  }
}
```

lib/index.ts:

```
import "zone.js";
import "rxjs";
import "reflect-metadata";
import "es6-shim";

import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import {About} from "./about";

bootstrap(About).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

lib/about.ts

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "about-page",
    template: `
        <h2>About</h2>
        This widget shows the weather forecast of Utrecht.
        The next 24 hours are shown under 'Today' and the forecast of 24-48 hours ahead under 'Tomorrow'.
        `
})
export class About {

}
```

lib/tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
    }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var small = require('small').gulp;
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var tsProject = typescript.createProject('lib/tsconfig.json', {
    typescript: require('typescript')
});

gulp.task('compile', function() {
    return gulp.src('lib/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .pipe(small('index.js', {
            externalResolve: ['node_modules'],
            globalModules: {
                "crypto": {
                    standalone: "undefined"
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static/scripts'));
});
gulp.task('release', ['compile'], function() {
    return gulp.src('static/scripts/scripts.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static/scripts'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['compile']);
```

static/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Weather</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <about-page>Loading..</about-page>
        </div>
        <script src="scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I run "gulp", I load the index.html in the browser and I get that error.

I have a node_modules folder created dynamically which contains an angular2 folder...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I checked my index.js generated file and

`var RuntimeMetadataResolver = (function () {`

is present. 
Moreover,

`exports.COMPILER_PROVIDERS`

contains

`__small$_xxx.RuntimeMetadataResolver`

EDIT2: No error in `npm ls` command

Comment: Unfortunately, your book is using an outdated version of Angular 2; there have been numerous, substantial changes since beta 17. Consider learning Angular 2 using the [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/).

Comment: But i'm studying typescript... Angular version is 2.0 beta 17 and the sample in the book uses the same version. I have installed it using 'npm install'. How can i edit my files?

Comment: The error you encounter is Angular 2 specific. For your purpose of learning TypeScript, I recommend you find a different example from your book rather than an outdated Angular 2 example.

Comment: So there is not way to let it works...also other samples are outdated.

Comment: If I were you.. maybe return the book? Perhaps something like this: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html online works better for you?

Comment: Typescript Blueprint

Comment: Sorry but i think there isn't an answer eligible for bounty, so i won't award my bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be not an issue with Angular, nor TypeScript, but the module bundler Small had a bug. A file `a/b` could be compiled twice (under conditions), namely as `a/b` and `a\b`. This only happened on Windows. This broke some functionality of Angular. Can you try to update to `small@0.2.8`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade from beta to latest version of angular and try.

Try using "npm update"

Answer (score -1):

you should import it in the **root module class** according to the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html). 
In your case it should be:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, RuntimeMetadataResolver],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Where is root module class? I'm following sample from a book. I have one directory and relative files

Comment: I recommend the angular2 documentation. There it is written what is the root module class.

Comment: My book is about typescript. I bought it before learning angular. 

Can you explain to me how it's related to my project (that is using also gulp)? Maybe have i to edit a file in node_modules/angular2 folder? 

I tried to create ts file containing code you wrote and adding imports. It didn't work. Your answer didn't help me. Can you improve it? Thanks

Comment: @Zimas: Emanuele is using an old beta version of Angular 2 which doesn't support modules.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: i answered you in the previous post.